# Mutating elements inside iterator

Tags: rust

I would like to iterate over some elements inside a vector contained as a member in a struct called `Test`. The idea is to mutate `Test` independently in each iteration and signify success if some external logic on each mutated `Test` is successful. For simplicity, the mutation is just changing the vector element to `123u8`. The problem I have is not being able to change the elements inside a loop. I have two solutions which I though would give the same answer:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    vec: Vec<u8>
}

impl Test {
    fn working_solution(&mut self, number: u8) -> bool {
        self.vec[0] = number;
        self.vec[1] = number;
        self.vec[2] = number;
        
        true
    }
    
    fn non_working_solution(&mut self, number: u8) -> bool {
        self.vec.iter().all(|mut x| {
            x = &number; // mutation
            true // external logic
        })
    }
}


fn main() {

    let vec = vec![0u8,1u8,2u8];
    let mut test = Test { vec };
    
    println!("Original: {:?}", test);
    test.working_solution(123u8);
    println!("Altered: {:?}", test);
    
    let vec = vec![0u8,1u8,2u8];
    let mut test = Test { vec };
    println!("Original: {:?}", test);
    test.non_working_solution(123u8);
    println!("Altered: {:?}", test);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bedff78b428b815d29a3e268d142157e))

Output:

```
Original: Test { vec: [0, 1, 2] }
Altered: Test { vec: [123, 123, 123] }
Original: Test { vec: [0, 1, 2] }
Altered: Test { vec: [0, 1, 2] }
```

Expected output:

```
Original: Test { vec: [0, 1, 2] }
Altered: Test { vec: [123, 123, 123] }
Original: Test { vec: [0, 1, 2] }
Altered: Test { vec: [123, 123, 123] }
```

---

How do I change a member of `self` when using an iterator?

Comment: Use `.iter_mut()` instead of `.iter()`?  Also you are currently overwriting the closure’s parameter `x`, which initially refers to the element, with a new value; instead you want to overwrite the *referant* by *dereferencing*: `*x = number;`.  The parameter `x` does not *itself* need to be mutable: with `iter_mut` it is of type `&mut u8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter), `ìter` takes a `&self`, that is, whatever you do, you can not modify `self` (you can create a modified copy, but this is not the point of what you want to do here).

Instead, you can use the method [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut), which is more or less the same, but takes a `&mut self`, i.e., you can modify it.

An other side remark, you don't want to use `all`, which is used to check if a property is true on all elements (hence the `bool` returned), instead, you want to use `for_each` which applies a function to all elements.

```
fn non_working_solution(&mut self, number: u8) {
    self.vec.iter_mut().for_each(|x| {
        *x = number; // mutation
    })
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21b6d9b08aa3c60278f6672cf278f9cd))

---

As Stargateur mentioned in the comments, you can also use a for loop:

```
fn non_working_solution(&mut self, number: u8) {
    for x in self.vec.iter_mut() {
        *x = number
    }
}
```

Comment: styte warning: for_each make no sense, functional style doesn't fit side effect, unless one have a very very good reason 99.9% of case you should use a simple and clear for loop.

Comment: I think OP asking for a solution using iterator is one of the very good reason to use iterator and their associated functions. Also, I think your warning is more opinion based than a consensus.

Comment: from doc "It’s generally more idiomatic to use a for loop, but for_each may be more legible when processing items at the end of longer iterator chains. In some cases for_each may also be faster than a loop, because it will use internal iteration on adapters like Chain." https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each. The real problem is that chain is a pain to optimize and even use for_each doesn't at all guaranty better result (and there is zero proof that it's actually better with chain), one should avoid chain and not use for_each anyway.

Comment: Again, OP asked for a solution with an iterator, their MWE is from a vector, but we don't know what it is in practice. (That being said, I added your proposition for completeness).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about ```ìter_mut```. Although my contrived example did not capture my complete intention. Would it be possible to make use of ```self``` after each mutation in the for loop? I am getting "cannot borrow `self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable". https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d81e4593d265945a3889613d4cdebddb

Comment: Actually I read some, it's seem for_each allow nice optimization but that still a niche opti, I would still advice to either not use chain or avoid side effect. I really don't get why them wanted a `for_each` method when you can do [that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b167ab6898f23ebeb7df18d94ec9eab), that still ugly in my opinion cause the side effect in functional style but at least collect is a functional style return on this case... `()`. But again I would almost never make a function that return nothing in my code.

Comment: @Kevin No you cannot use `self` there. The lambda inside the `for_each` captures the `self`. It makes sense, if you think about it. Iterating over an element in `self` with `iter_mut` puts the `self` in a mutable borrowed state. Until the `iter_mut` is over, you can't use `self` for anything else, as you cannot borrow both mutable and non-mutable at the same time. That's one of the challenges that makes Rust hard for former C/C++ programmers, because many of the concepts/constructs of C/C++ do not apply to Rust any more.

Answer (score 2):

Since Rust 1.50, there is a dedicated method for filling a slice with a value — [`[_]::fill`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.fill):

```rust
self.vec.fill(number)
```

In this case, `fill` seems to generate less code than a `for` loop or `for_each`:

([Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/PrdKenvxe))

```rust
pub fn f(slice: &mut [u8], number: u8) {
    slice.fill(number);
}

pub fn g(slice: &mut [u8], number: u8) {
    for x in slice {
        *x = number;
    }
}

pub fn h(slice: &mut [u8], number: u8) {
    slice
        .iter_mut()
        .for_each(|x| *x = number);
}
```

```
example::f:
  mov rax, rsi
  mov esi, edx
  mov rdx, rax
  jmp qword ptr [rip + memset@GOTPCREL]

example::g:
  test rsi, rsi
  je .LBB1_2
  push rax
  mov rax, rsi
  movzx esi, dl
  mov rdx, rax
  call qword ptr [rip + memset@GOTPCREL]
  add rsp, 8
.LBB1_2:
  ret

example::h:
  test rsi, rsi
  je .LBB2_1
  mov rax, rsi
  movzx esi, dl
  mov rdx, rax
  jmp qword ptr [rip + memset@GOTPCREL]
.LBB2_1:
  ret
```